# Ctrl+Shift+R versus Ctrl+r with the browser

Tags: http, browser, request

My server receives *two* GET requests when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in the browser. But when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, my server only receives 1 GET request. Why does my server receive 2 requests when using shift? (I believe using the shift key will clear cookies or something).

Comment: Can you share your client side code?

Comment: Client side code is just refreshing the browser at a certain endpoint - so  a simple GET request to a URL

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome sends multiple requests to fetch a page, and that's -apparently- not a bug, but a feature. And we as developers just have to deal with it.

As far as I could dig out in five minutes, chrome does that just to make the surfing faster, so if one connection gets lost, the second will take over.

I guess if the website is well developed, then it's functionality won't break by this, because multiple requests are just not new.